# Django model field _('name')?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm reading the django.contrib.auth.models.py file and I see this being done all over the place:

```
name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=255)
```

I believe 'name' is the option designating the name of the database column to use for this field.  But what does surrounding it with _('...') mean?  And what's the advantage to doing that?

Comment: What you are seeing is lazy translation objects. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/translation/#working-with-lazy-translation-objects